# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot

I'm unable to run springboot application because of below error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error caused by an illegal mix of spring versions.

Try to run `mvn dependency:tree` and see whether there are different versions of spring mixed in the classpath.